# JENA - get value from RDF

Tags: java, xml, rdf, sparql, jena

Sorry, i am again here, because i have a fast question,for example if i have this rdf:

```
<rdf:RDF
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
 xmlns:ts="http://www.test.com/testModel.owl#">  
<ts:Entity rdf:ID="1234_test"> 
   <ts:Resource> 
       <ts:testProp rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">test_ID_test</ts:testProp>
 </ts>
</ts>
</rdf:RDF>
```

How i can extract the value test_ID_test??? And if i want use SPARQL how can i do with jena???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For running a SPARQL query using Jena, see the [ARQ documentation](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/app_api.html) or the [Jena SPARQL](http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/sparql.html) tutorial.

As for your query, it depends how you want to identify the resource. If you know *a priori* the URI of the resource, it's straightforward:

```
prefix ts: <http://www.test.com/testModel.owl#>
select ?tp_value where {
  ts:1234_test ts:testProp ?tp_value
}
```

If you happen to know only that it's a resource of type `Entity`, the query is only slightly more involved:

```
prefix ts: <http://www.test.com/testModel.owl#>
select ?tp_value where {
  ?entity a ts:Entity ;
            ts:testProp ?tp_value
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answare but in that case the response is: test_ID_testy^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string. You know how to get only test_ID_test??

Comment: When you call the `toString()` method on a Jena value, it returns a value useful for debugging, including the datatype. Since what you actually have is a Jena [`Literal`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Literal.html) object, to get the lexical form of the literal as it appeared in the data use the `getLexicalForm()` method, and to get the actual value (e.g. if it's a double or int) use `.getValue()`.